# Output bibliography with pandoc-citeproc without citing anything

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I am using `pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc` to generate a pdf file from a series of markdown files. My references are in `sources.bib`, my citation format is in `apa.csl`, my metadata is in `default.yaml`, a second piece of metadata (containing title, author, date, and abstract) are in `meta.md`, and I also have `paper.md` and `outline.md`.

I am currently attempting to produce a document which consists of my title page, abstract, outline, and references. Because my outline does not contain any citations my reference page is blank. I cannot find any flag in either `pandoc` or `pandoc-citeproc` which would force my references to show without any citations. When I include `paper.md`, which does contain citations, than my reference page works as expected.

The command I am trying to use to produce my paper is:

`pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc default.yaml meta.md outline.md -o outline.pdf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to add citations without mentioning them in the text by specifying them in the `nocite` metadata field. Using the special citation `@*` triggers the inclusion of all references in the bibliography.

```
---
nocite: '@*'
---
```

Adding this line to your metadata should do the trick.

Comment: Wonderful thanks, that did the trick! Much cleaner than my current solution of citing all sources on their own page and then having to remove that page from the PDF.